# How to make httpd24 (scl) use php >= 7.2 (RHEL 6.10)?

Tags: httpd, rhel6, php7, scl

I am fairly new to working with RHEL and I was wondering if it was possible to have an httpd24 instanced installed as a software collection
`httpd24.x86_64    1.1-18.el6    @rhel-x86_64-server-6-rhscl-1` work with a PHP version other than the one included in the collection (7.0.10). Due to some incompatibilities with MySQL 8.0 I am seeing the need to update to 7.2.0 (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74461). I've tried installing it and linking the .so file it places in the httpd 2.2 system package into the httpd24 modules folder. However, I quickly found out that due to some interface differences between httpd 2.2 and httpd 2.4, the PHP install was incompatible.

I'm trying not to make things messy on the server as I am not the only one that uses it and some maintenance is actually performed by other people. Is there a straightforward way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

1/ I will heartily recommends to upgrade to RHEL-7 which have rh-php71 and rh-php72 collections (the only officially supported way)

2/ yes, httpd24 can use any PHP version, from any providers, using the fastcgi protocol (FPM)

As described in [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/)

I'm not aware of any provider of PHP packages which provides mod_php for this version.

3/ if you are used to run Software Collections, you can try the ones available in "remi" repository (7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 available for EL-6)

Following the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions (for multiple versions)

As SCL are designed for parallel installation, adding a new collection won't alter the base system, and you can easily run both versions simultaneously or switch from one to another.